# Can't get a simple ruby Example working for pubnub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pubnub

```
 require 'pubnub'

 pubnub = Pubnub.new(
        :publish_key => 'demo',
        :subscribe_key => 'demo'
    )

 pubnub.publish(
   :channel  => 'The Angular Channel',
   :message => 'Hello PubNub, love the Ruby SDK!',
 ) { |data| puts data.response }
```

I basically just followed the example from the SDK documentation page. I am not too sure what went wrong. as I try using the Angular Channel demo, I can successfully subscribe, but using this ruby script I can't seem to make it work.

the log is printed to the pubnub log.

```
Created new Pubnub::Client instance
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.940851 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Event#initialize | Initialized Pubnub::Publish
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.940972 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Publish#uri http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/demo/demo/0/The%20Angular%20Channel/0/%22Hello%20PubNub%2C%20love%20the%20Ruby%20SDK%21%22?pnsdk=PubNub-Ruby/3.7.1&uuid=065e1ab5-e87c-4fb2-a07d-b78bd8243610
I, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941349 #33052]  INFO -- pubnub: Bytesize: 189
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941445 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Publish#uri http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/demo/demo/0/The%20Angular%20Channel/0/%22Hello%20PubNub%2C%20love%20the%20Ruby%20SDK%21%22?pnsdk=PubNub-Ruby/3.7.1&uuid=065e1ab5-e87c-4fb2-a07d-b78bd8243610
I, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941521 #33052]  INFO -- pubnub: Length:   189
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941546 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Created event Pubnub::Publish
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941566 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::SingleEvent#fire
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941585 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::SingleEvent#fire | Adding event to async_events
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941604 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::SingleEvent#fire | Starting railgun
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941622 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_event_machine | starting EM in new thread
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.941641 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_event_machine | We aren't running on thin
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.948131 #33052] DEBUG -- pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_event_machine | EM started in new thread
D, [2015-06-14T16:54:05.948225 #33052] DEBUG -- Pubnub: Pubnub::Client#start_railgun | Initializing railgun
D, [2015-06-14T16:58:22.993076 #33140] DEBUG -- pubnub: Symbolizing options keys
D, [2015-06-14T16:58:22.993217 #33140] DEBUG -- pubnub: Setting default values
D, [2015-06-14T16:58:22.993306 #33140] DEBUG -- pubnub:
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I can't reproduce this. Please provide me more data about your development environment. Ruby version, Pubnub gem version, anything else that could help me reproduce your issue.

Comment: Chris, just following up to see if you still need help with this. To debug, try subscribing to the channel from the dev console just make sure you specify the same pub/sub keys and channel. Then run your Ruby script and see if the message shows up in the dev console. If it does then we would need to see your Angular code.